# How to get browser to save unmasked password input?

Tags: javascript, html, input, passwords

How to get a browser to save HTML **password** input when the password is **unmasked**?

I have an HTML input with a `type="password"`. I wish to unmask it by setting its type to text, which seems like a common way of achieving this kind of unmasking.

Now the problem is, that if the user unmasks the password, and then sends the form, the browser will not ask to save the password. How to get the browser to ask for saving when the password is unmasked? Without somehow programmatically masking it during form sent?

Comment: *"Without somehow programmatically masking it during form send?"* Why is this not a valid option?

Comment: I agree I'm pretty sure this is the only way

Comment: Im building an individual component that does not know about its surroundings. The users of the component would all then have to implement this feature of masking it during form sent, which is cumbersome. I wish there would be a better option

Comment: You could add two inputs, one of type `password` and the other `text` and just switch between them with some styling. Just make sure when the user types in one the other input value updates. Not the prettiest but it should work

Comment: try to change `type="password"` on form submit

Comment: Having 2 inputs might lead to some accessibility problems hmm... The component has high accessibility requirements.

Comment: Having 2 inputs would also then add 2 inputs to the form, and the user of the component would have to filter the second input while submitting the form